# How to redirect one url to another using .htacces?

Tags: .htaccess

I have an url like www.example.com/xyz
I want to redirect it to www.example.com/abc

xyz and abc can be a long string, what .htaccess rule I should use?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your content was moved permanently? :) In that case it is best to use a permanent (301) redirect rule in your .htaccess file

```
Redirect permanent /xyz http://www.domain.com/abc
```

or

```
Redirect 301 /xyz http://www.domain.com/abc
```

If this does not solve your problem, please specify the nature of your redirect.
Happy to help!

Comment: Nope, it's not working for me. See, I have a url structure like this,
www.example.com/laptops/wipro/wipro-e.go-(wnbofhc)-b93d I want people to be redirected to www.example.com/laptops/wipro/wipro-e.go-wnbofhc-b93d here. Both of the urls have same content, so I just want to justify a single url.